# Layout XML File or Values XML File?

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-studio

[image: immage]

I need to create a new file XML in my project, but I'm uncertain.

Someone can explain me what are the differnt between the Layout XML File and the Values XML File so I can choose what type of XML I should use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a new layout file (for design) then choose *Layout XML File*.

If you want to create any other resourse file like color, string, etc. then choose *Values XML File*.

HTH - is it OK now or want to understood more?

Comment: Thanks, now I understund the differences!

Comment: Welcome always @IanGallegos